# вопрос по input и экранированию

Tags: python

Всем привет! Есть скрипт Python, все работает, но есть одно неудобство: в коде есть пара мест, в которых пользователь должен вставить путь к файлу. и так как \ надо экранировать, то приходится писать \\, например C:\\papka\\file.txt что неудобно, хотелось бы чтобы пользователь мог просто скопировать и вставить C:\papka\file.txt Как этого добиться? код примерно такой:

```
perv = input ('Укажите путь к изменяемому файлу, \ замени на \\\: ')
vtor = input ('Куда сохранить измененный файл, \ замени на \\\: ')
inp = open (perv, 'r')
out = open (vtor, 'w')
```

Comment: По идеи, можно попробовать другой слеш: `C:/papka/file.txt`

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы, r'' помогло!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слеш экранируется только в **исходном коде**.  Не путайте строковую константу в коде (текстовое представление строки) и соответствующую строку (сам объект) в памяти.

К примеру, `"\t"` в исходном коде создаёт строку с одним символом (tab). Но, если вызвать `input()` (Python 3) и набрать `"\t"`, то результат уже: `'"\\t"'` (четыре символа: две кавычки + слеш + t). Чтобы получить tab, достаточно клавишу <kbd>Tab</kbd> нажать для `input()`.

```
>>> len('\t') == 1
True
>>> len('\\t') == 2
True
>>> r'\t' == '\\t'
```

В последнем примере используется raw string literal. Оба выражения создают одну и ту же строку (в памяти никаких `r''`, только обычные строки/объекты).

При вводе/выводе слеш экранировать не нужно, если вы не пытаетесь ввод интерпретировать как исходный код Питона.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать спецификатор `r` для строки, который обозначает - строка вводится в сыром формате(экранировать при этом ничего не надо). Одинаково хорошо подходит как для регулярных выражений, так и для путей:

```
 r"D:\Project\2014\archdata\folder1.ini"
```

спецификатор можно задавать в верхнем регистре

Плюсы такого решения в том, что не падает читабельность по сравнению с экранированием.